# Ghidra: Script to set references for array of relative pointers

Tags: ghidra

I'm having trouble creating a script to set references for an array of relative pointers in Ghidra. The array contains 1784 elements so it's not feasible to convert them by hand. The pointers are relative to themselves so `(*ptr + ptr) % 0x10000000` is the equation to convert them to actual pointers.

Can anyone help me find a script to set the references for these 1784 relative pointers?

I've tried the Ghidra Python console, but I can't get the address of the pointers as an unsigned u32.